# vscode extension CustomTextEditor Drag'n Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, listener, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to drop `TreeViewItem` into my `CustomEditor`.
I've implemented a `DocumentDropEditProvider` that is working well for a "normal" text editor.
But I don't know how to make it work on my `CustomTextEditor` or its `webView`.
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

I've cloned the vscode and run it in debug mode and I don't see any place where a Drag and Drop Listener would have been registered for the `CustomTextEditor` (besides the one that handles the shift key/editor open).

Is it something that one can do or should I look into using webView instead of treeView to have a better control of Drag and Drop listener ?